# Why doesn't click event fire after mouseDown event on same element fires?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a `mouseDown` event and a click event on the same element.  When I click on it, the `mouseDown` event fires (i.e. alerts "Mouse pressed on P"), but the click event doesn't.  However, if I comment out the `mouseDown` alert statement, the click event does display its alert.  Why is this?  http://jsfiddle.net/A8vhq/

Comment: instead of alert, try console.log, you will see both the events fired. check the explanation over here http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thanks all ... I'm actually not using alerts for testing, just learning about and experimenting with various mouse events and couldn't understand this behavior.

Comment: DG3, I looked and that link and didn't see anything that would explain this specific observation/behavior?

Comment: The explanation for click event when mouse is clicked. The click event triggers only when the mouse button that is pressed has to be released. Since you were using alert, the mouse release is getting blocked, hence click event is not happening

Comment: Yes I knew that the mouse button had to be pressed and released, I just didn't know that an alert interrupts that sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the click never happens, when the alert box appears it interrupts the mouseup event on the element, thus interrupting mouseclick.

use `console.log('message')` to test your code instead of `alert`.

Comment: If someone needs to use a modal - for example, in order to interrupt the click to run code, then complete the click on modal close - how can they get around this issue. It only crops up in Firefox for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `alert`, use `console.log` and it will work.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/A8vhq/1/

---

Btw, I've refactored the code a bit:

```
$('p').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log('Mouse pressed on ' + e.target.nodeName);
});

$('p').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.nodeName + ' clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `alert` with `console.log` or any other **non-modal** output way.